# Is there a name for this UI deign pattern? A group of views that are related by state and hierarchical?

Tags: user-interface, design-patterns, responsive-design, single-page-application

Example:  I have an SPA Angular app; but this might apply to everything from MVC to Winforms..

There is a sale process(could be another related process, just an example) which includes UI views for:

1. Choose OR Create Customer
2. Add Items to Work Order
3. Cash Out Sale

Traits are:

- These are conceptually related.
- You have to access them in some order. Cannot start at 2+ for example.
- State is persisted in this "flow(don't know better word)"

I am confronting things like, state between UI views, etc and would like to know how to describe the pattern.

**Edit: 2**
I have significantly edited the title and contents to not seem to apply to Angular Framework.

Comment: I believe they call this [Stepper](https://material.angular.io/components/stepper/overview) in material design.

Comment: Thx..  For all I know, there is no name..  Or the name could apply to everything down to say, c# Winforms opening Modals..

Answer (score 0):

You could migrate these three components into their own Module which you could import into your AppModule. Also, for this new Module you could create a custom routing module `ng g m sales --routing true` where you could do modify the routes array to do something like this.

```
const routes: Routes = [{
    path: 'sales',
    children: [{
        path: 'step-1',
        component: ComponentOne
    }, {
        path: 'step-2',
        component: ComponentTwo
    }, {
        path: 'step-3',
        component: ComponentThree
    }]
}];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class SalesRoutingModule { }
```

I wouldn't say that there is a name to this pattern per se, however with the application of a concept called LazyLoading this is considered a requirement. And the concept of putting related components/routes into their own module is described in the [Angular Style Guide](http://angular.io/guide/styleguide#application-structure-and-ngmodu%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bles) (if you would like to look into that)

The style guide does advise a methodology called LIFT which to me seems fairy generic to any web development. It's just a slew of best practices for your coding structure.

Comment: I am using angular 4.  But am looking for a name to the pattern.  Having all in one module makes sense..  I have a handful of questions related to the pattern.

Comment: I wouldn't say that there is a name to this pattern per se, however with the application of a concept called LazyLoading this is considered a requirement. And the concept of putting related components/routes into their own module is described in the Angular Style Guide (if you would like to look into that) https://angular.io/guide/styleguide#application-structure-and-ngmodules

Comment: See my Edit 1.  I am not looking for details specific to Angular 2+.

Comment: The style guide does advise a methodology called LIFT which to me seems fairy generic to any web development. It's just a slew of best practices for your coding structure. I know the term has been used for AngularJS (v. 1), and have seen it applied with other frameworks as well.

Comment: I love the T, for Try to be DRY in LIFT.  Thanks for suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Do you know about 'Auth Guards' in angular 2?
You can easily handle user directly inputting URL.

Detailed explanation of 'Auth Guard' is [here](http://www.sparkbit.pl/angular-2-route-guards-real-life-example/).

**Above explanation only works with angular 2+.**

Comment: I am using auth guards , but would like to know if there is a name to the pattern.